# Why isn't my element's style changing when I assign to element.style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to write an event listener that moves an element where I move my mouse, by setting properties of the CSSStyleDeclaration object on the element:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function moveOverlay(evt){
  overlay.style.left = evt.clientX;
  overlay.style.top = evt.clientY;
});
```

However, after each assignment to a property of `style` runs, the value (as checked in the debugger) doesn't change - it remains the default empty string value `''`. A change like `overlay.style.color = 'blue'` works - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS style rules will only be assigned as a property value if they are syntactically valid - if the prospective value is invalid for the CSS rule in question, the operation will be ignored. Numbers for CSS properties need a unit suffix to be valid - in this case, it needs to be specified that the positions are in *pixels*. Try `evt.clientX + 'px'` instead.